# Generating pseudo-random number within a classes's function

Tags: python, random

I am trying to make a q table.
But as I am creating my q table I notice that all of my values are the same even as I changed the random.seed and used multiple variants of randint, such as np.random.uniform and random.uniform.
My code is below

```
import os, time, random

start = time.time()

class space_info:
    SIZE = 10


class blob():
    value = None
    q_table = {}

    def init(self):
        SIZE = space_info.SIZE
        for i in range(-SIZE+1, SIZE):
            for ii in range(-SIZE+1, SIZE):
                for iii in range(-SIZE+1, SIZE):
                    for iiii in range(-SIZE+1, SIZE):
                        random.seed(time.time()*1000000)
                        self.q_table[((i, ii), (iii, iiii))] = [random.uniform(-5, 0) for i in range(4)]

    

os.system('clear')
x = blob()
x.init()
z = blob()
z.init()
if (z.q_table[((-9, -2), (3, 9))]) == (x.q_table[((-9, -2), (3, 9))]):
    print("WE FAILED ):")
    print(z.q_table[((-9, -2), (3, 9))])
    print(x.q_table[((-9, -2), (3, 9))])

else:
    print("YES")
```

How can I get new numbers for my q_table?

Comment: Do ***not*** reseed the generator for every call to the PRNG.  Seed once and only once per program, unless you really really really understand how PRNGs work and are trying to implement so-called "variance reduction" through correlation induction strategies.

Comment: There is no reason for you to be calling `random.seed()` at all in this code.  If you must use it, calling it *once* at the top would be sufficient.

Comment: Also note that `random` and `np.random` are completely separate implementations. Using the `seed()` function from one does nothing to the other. In other words, you must use the `seed()` function corresponding to the generator you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `q_table` belongs to class blob not instances of class blob.
You can test this by `id(x.q_table) == id(z.q_table)`. If this is true it means that both are in the same place in memory.

```
class blob():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None
        self.q_table = {}
        # in case you don't want to call init explicitly
        # self.init()
   
    def init(self):
       ...
```

I have left the `init` function as it was.

The `__init__` function is what the class should now use to create a new instance of blob. Note that `q_table` is now `self.q_table` indicating it belongs to the object referred to as `self`, i.e., the instance of class blob.